# Cohomology of real analytic coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, singularity-theory, real-algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $M$ be a real analytic variety
(if someone is concerned about distinction between
"real analytic spaces" and "real analytic varieties"
in real analytic geometry, let's assume that $M$ 
is both "variety" and "space"). I was sure it is
well-known that higher cohomology of any 
real analytic coherent sheaf over $M$ vanish.

The argument is standard: by Grauert, a real analytic variety is the set
of real points in a Stein variety $M_{C}$ with an anticomplex involution $v$. A coherent sheaf over $M$ is the set of $v$-invariant sections 
of a $v$-equivariant coherent sheaf $F_{C}$ on $M_{C}$, and $F_C$ has
vanishing cohomology because $M_C$ is Stein.

Recently I needed a reference to this fact, and
I could not find it. I would be extremely grateful
for a reference!

Comment: For smooth analytic manifolds, the reference is Proposition 2.3 in Atiyah and Hirzebruch's "Analytic cycles on complex manifolds", https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938362900940

Comment: Many thanks. They don't seem to use the smoothness, in fact, the argument is almost literally the same as I gave. Still, the reference to the full strength statement would be extremely helpful.

Comment: That's because Grauert's paper [On Levi's problem and the imbedding of real-analytic manifolds](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mat&paperid=135&option_lang=eng) (sorry about russian version, the english one is behind paywall) which they are citing deals with smooth analytic manifolds. Do you know the reference for existence of complexification in a non-smooth case?

Comment: Sure: for non-smooth varieties it is actually a definition, see
Guaraldo, F., Macri, P., Tancredi, A.,
{\em Topics on real analytic spaces},
 Advanced lectures in mathematics, Braunschweig: F. Vieweg, 1986.

Comment: another possibly useful reference is Henri Cartan, [Variétés analytiques réelles et variétés
analytiques complexes](http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1957__85__77_0.pdf). He establishes theorems A and B for _coherent_ (globally defined by a finite number of analytic functions, or, equivalently, supports of coherent sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$-modules) analytic subvarieties of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Many thanks! This is almost it, at least very close, but not quite: he never mentions cohomology of coherent sheaves.

Comment: Theoreme 3 on page 89 is the statement about cohomology

Comment: thanks! That's it. I did a search on "cohomology", but he uses $H^q$ instead.

Comment: Could you just write it as a reply? I want to close the question as solved. Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a smooth case, the reference is Proposition 2.3 in Atiyah and Hirzebruch's [Analytic cycles on complex manifolds](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938362900940).

For a non-smooth case, I don't know the general reference, but Theoreme 3 in Henri Cartan's paper [Variétés analytiques réelles et variétés analytiques complexes](http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1957__85__77_0.pdf)
establishes theorems A and B for *coherent* (supports of coherent analytic sheaves) analytic subvarieties of $\mathbb{R}^n$